# C# cast polymorphic object into specific type without knowing what that 'specific type' is

Tags: c#, generics, casting, polymorphism

Thanks ahead, community!

As the title describes, I would like to cast an object that is in parent type to a child type, which is actually a child type, whilst this 'specific type' cannot be known until runtime.

Lets say I have following data holder:

```
public class Holder {}

public class Holder<T> : Holder
{
    public T Value;
}
```

And this Holder (not Holder<T>) will be given to some script at runtime.

I need to cast this Holder into Holder<T> (eg, Holder<string>), so that I can access the Value : T.

For now, I can just mannually add casting cases and their coresponding methods to process it, but time by time there will be more types that goes into this Holder<T>, and it would become imposible to manage in this way.

Is there a way to accomplish this objective?

This Holder must not be flattened, as it is being used in a context as below:

```
public class SomeNode
{
    protected Holder holder;
}
public class SomeNode<T> : SomeNode
{
    public SomeNode<T>()
    {
        holder = new Holder<T>();
    }
}
```

I have no clue how to approach this, nor a search keyword to catch a hint about this.
Automatic suggestions came up before posting seems not my case, which were:

[C# Create (or cast) objects of a specific type at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570139/c-sharp-create-or-cast-objects-of-a-specific-type-at-runtime)

[C# Accessing generic Method without knowing specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963402/c-sharp-accessing-generic-method-without-knowing-specific-type)

---

### Edit

Thanks to @W.F., I could start searching with an effective keyword 'dynamic object', and I ended up finding System.Reflection as my desired soultion.

It looks like as belows and currently it solves my immediate issue:

```
holder.GetType().GetProperty("GetValue").Invoke(holder, null);
```

But as pointed out by @OlivierJacot-Descombes, my structure and a way of using it is breaking a purpose of polymorphism. Therefore I still need a better solution, which would do a job I am looking for and also not breaking polymorphism.

Possible walkaround that comes in my head is that, first, create a method GetValue() in Holder, and also create class that inherits from Holder to implement this method:

```
public class Holder
{
    public virtual string GetValue() => "";
}

public class Holder<T> : Holder
{
    public T Value;
}

public class FloatHolder : Holder<float> //for example
{
    public override string GetValue() => Value.ToString();
}
```

Second, change node structure like:

```
public class SomeNode
{
    protected Holder holder;
}
public class SomeNode<T> : SomeNode {}
public class FloatNode : SomeNode<float>
{
    public FloatNode()
    {
        holder = new FloatHolder();
    }
}
```

Then, I can do like:

```
public class EchoNode : SomeNode
{
    public void Tick()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(holder.GetValue());
    }
}
```

Seems like too many classes are being created, but it also seems not breaking polymorphism.

Looking for further advices. Again, Thanks!

---

### Edit#2

I already said this in the comment, but for better readability, I write this here as well.

Both *Dynamic Object* and *System.Reflection* were easy and fitting solutions which **I was looking for**, but they weren't **best solutions** in general.

At the beginning I was misinterpreting @OlivierJacot-Descombes 's answer. He was overall pointing out two impediments: first, my class structure is breaking polymorphism, and second, reflection is slow (and later I noticed, dynamic object as well). I didn't catch the last bit at first so I went through a long way.

Moreover, turned out, I couldn't use dynamic object for my project context, as I am not using normal C# but a Unity C#. Technically I can, but they don't blend well.

Thankfully, my revised solution was acceptable. Therefore I decided to select @OlivierJacot-Descombes 's post as an answer. But I hope, still, people would approach and leave me an good advices.

Thank you all.

Comment: What do you think about explicit/implicit operators using?

Comment: Can you please show example usage of this hierarchies? And code that represents the actual problem you are experiencing/trying to solve?

Comment: I think this was a good idea, but not, we can't use a explicit operators in generic.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941509/can-i-use-a-generic-implicit-or-explicit-operator-c-sharp

Comment: Why don't you just want to create a constructor like a
```
public class Holder<T>
{
public Holder(Holder a, T = default) {...}
}
```

Comment: I don't see the benefits of casting at runtime, as cast is a compile time thingy, maybe you are looking for dynamic objects?

Comment: what about this? `Holder<T> typedHolder = holder as Holder<T>;

// Check if the result of the cast is not null
if (typedHolder != null)
{
    // The holder object is a Holder<T>, so you can access the Value property
    T value = typedHolder.Value;`

Comment: @ValeriyVartumyan yeah, operators weren't useful in this case, as it will become like:
    public static implicit/explicit operator SOMTHING(Holder h)
while this SOMEHING is still unknown.

Comment: @ValeriyVartumyan On the other hand, your second comment isn't my case at all. Although I didn't know that default type could be given to T, having default type has no effect as Holder alone will not be instantiated. It will always be Holder<T>, saved in a List<Holder>

Comment: @GuruStron My actual class names are Holder -> Result, SomeNode -> Node. class Result is being used to handle over Node's processed values to the other Nodes. Most of nodes inherits from Node<T> as their value or a job of them are type specific. However, EchoNode inherits from Node, since this node is designed to print the Result<T> regardless of what T actually is. Due to hierarchy, EchoNode only owns Result, but not Result<T>, resulting public T Value becomes unaccessable.

Comment: @W.F. Thank you very much! It's my first time of hearing what dynamic object is. Quite embarrassing. In my short search it seams like dynamic keyword is only useable for any class that inherits System.DynamicObject. Would changing class Holder into class Holder : System.DynamicObject fix my issue? I guess worth trying it.

Comment: @viveknuna Well, that is the exact thing that I am already doing. I posted this as I needed an expandable solution. But still thank you for your commitment.

Comment: What you desire would probably be something like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/x95V0J (in the example there is no point of explicit casting when the object type is known at runtime, but we accept it)

Comment: @W.F. Thank you very much! It works very nicely on a standalone unit testing. Although, it turned out I cannot use it. All these are to run in a Unity C# context, and it seems dynamic keyword is well known to not work well with Unity C# according to Unity Forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to cast to a specific type, you are doing polymorphism wrong. Of course you could do something like this:

```cs
switch (holder)
{
    case Holder<string> stringHolder:
        DoStringThing(stringHolder.Value);
        break;
    case Holder<int> intHolder:
        DoIntThing(intHolder.Value);
        break;
    ...
}
```

See also: [Switch statements with patterns](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/new-features-in-c-7-0/#switch-statements-with-patterns).

However, the idea behind polymorphism is to be able to do things without having to know the specific type. Therefore, re-design the holder classes and have them do the type specific thing themselves:

```cs
public abstract class Holder
{
    public abstract void DoThing();
}

public abstract class Holder<T> : Holder
{
    public abstract T Value { get; }
}
```

Some examples of specific types:

```cs
public class StringHolder : Holder<string>
{
    public StringHolder(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string Value { get; }

    public override void DoThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"String of length {Value.Length} is \"{Value}\"");
    }
}

public class IntHolder : Holder<int>
{
    public IntHolder(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override int Value { get; }

    public override void DoThing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The integer {Value} is {(Value % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd")}");
    }
}
```

Now you can simply write

```cs
holder.DoThing();
```

... without having to cast.

---

**Update**

Your edited question indeed shows a polymorphic version.

Here I want to present another approach which merges `Holder` and `Holder<T>` in a single class through the use of interfaces.

```cs
public interface IHolder
{
    object Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IHolder<T> : IHolder
{
    new T Value { get; set; } // The new keyword hides the inherited property.
}

public class Holder<T> : IHolder<T>
{
    object IHolder.Value
    {
        get => Value; // Returns T Holder<T>.Value as object.
        set => Value = value is T t ? t : default; // Sets T Holder<T>.Value.
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

`Holder<T>` now implements a "neutral" `Value` property declared in `IHolder` based on the `object` type. Since it implements it explicitly (i.e., instead of `public object Value` we write `object IHolder.Value`), this property is hidden, unless it is accessed through the interface. This allows you, for example, to declare a `List<IHolder>` and to retrieve different kinds of `Holder<T>` values with `list[i].Value` as object.

But you have a variable `Holder<float> floatHolder`, you can get the strongly typed `float` value.

Note that this still allows you do derive more specific types like `class FloatHolder : Holder<float>`, but it might not even be necessary.

If you intend to work only with derived types, you can mark `Holder<T>` as abstract and also all the members that must be implemented by the deriving classes. This makes it impossible to create an instance of `Holder<T>` with `new` and also allows you to declare abstract methods without body.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Secondly, I was intentionally doing so, so unless I find a better fitting solution, I cannot turn from this way. One fact I know is that EVERY Holder instances that will exist in a runtime will be in type of Holder<T>. One other thing is that, I currently have no plan to create classes that inherits from Holder<T>. Instances of Holder<T> is being created as shown in my second code block. However, if I make one, it could be my solution, as absence of such T.ToString() is the reason why I posted this question. Simple public virtual string GetValue() would do.

Comment: There is no `T.ToString()` because `T` is a type. But there is a `holder.Value.ToString()` and also a `holder.ToString()` even when `holder is a `Holder<T>` and the generic type parameter is unknown. The latter `ToString` must be overridden to make something useful. You can also get the type name with `typeof(T).Name` or `typeof(T).ToString()` where `typeof` returns a `System.Type` object.

Comment: This was a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because you asked about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.

Comment: Maybe yes, it is a XY problem. But please understand, as that must be caused of me, knowing not where to start with before I wrote this post. Great thanks to @W.F. in a comment, with a keyword dynamic object I could start searching effectively. There I could find a System.Reflection which seems like a best fitting solution I was looking for. `holder.GetType().GetProperty("GetValue").Invoke(holder, null);` feels like my desired result, but this is still breaking polymorphism. On this ground, would you give me a better walkaround that I can attrieve the same result without breaking polymorphism?

Comment: There is no point in getting a strongly typed value at runtime like this, because, since you do not know its type, you would be forced to do everything by Reflection from now on. This is a typical case of trying to do something dynamic with generics. But generic are by no means dynamic. They are **always** resolved at compile time. Given a **Holder<T> holder**, you can write `object value = holder.Value;` without knowing its type.

Comment: I guess your latest comment means that instead of keeping the current way, I should try to turn Holder into DynamicObject. Am I right? Also, please look at the last part of the post as I edited it. The edited content is mainly about what I understood from your comment. Please leave a comment about whether I interpreted your speech right or wrong, and an advice about it. Thank you.

Comment: If you are storing numeric types, you also might be interested in [C# 11's Generic math support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#generic-math-support).

Answer (score 0):

community! It's a good question. That was interesting.
I think this is simple solve for this question.
We just need to create a simple constructor like below

```
public class Holder
{
    public string SomeData;  // just example data

    public Holder()
    {
        
    }
    
    public Holder(Holder someData)
    {
        SomeData = someData.SomeData;
    }
}

public class Holder<T> : Holder
{
    public T Value;

    public Holder(Holder a, T t = default)
        :base(a)
    {
        Value = t;
    }
}

public class Programm
{
    void Main()
    {
        var h = new Holder();
        var g = new Holder<string>(h);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am kinda lost. Would you provide some extra explanation? I got 2 questions about your answer: 1) What is an use of string SomeData? Currently there is no vivid corelation between T Value and string SomeData. Since I will be always using T Value, string SomeData seems only occupying memory spaces. 2) What is a purpose of that constructor? It seems like, what it does is purely taking another Holder's SomeData and set it as self's SomeData, while T Value is left behind totally unrelated to SomeData.

Comment: 1) field SomeData there as commented only for showing how to don't lose data that holded in Holder at the Holder<T>
2) Copy Constructor there needed there to use this at Holder<T> class to easely create generic from base class